# Flood fill on a canny edge detection operated image in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, flood-fill

I am not very familiar with image processing techniques.

Working on a farm land image segmentation task using only traditional image processing technique.

Initially planned to first operate gaussian smoothening, then canny edge detection and then flood fill the image with black color to segment the farms, but it is really hard to tune the canny edge algorithm, and could not understand how to take an initial patch for flood fill operation.

Can someone suggest a python code which could give good result with flood fill operation on a 640*480 pixel image, and also what size of initial patch would be good?

Comment: Pretty much impossible to answer without seeing what your images look like.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).